What property should I pass so that it doesn't automatically try to build the docker image
Description
I have my Dockerfile in src/main/docker in the project's root folder.
And in pom.xml I've added code to trigger the image building only if a certain parameter is passed.
However, because of the fact I've put the Dockerfile in src/main/docker - the plugin automatically initiates the Docker image building. If the Dockerfile is in another folder - no problem.
So - what parameter(s) should I pass so that it doesn't do this automatically? ... And the logic for triggering the build depends only the CLI parameter I've configured?
PS: The current configuration is somewhat this one:
<image>
    <build>
        <dockerFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/docker/Dockerfile</dockerFile>
        <basedir>${project.basedir}</basedir>
        <contextDir>${project.basedir}</contextDir>
        <tags>
            <tag>${project.version}</tag>
        </tags>
    </build>
</image>

Info

docker-maven-plugin version : 4.4.0
Maven version (mvn -v) : 3.9.6
Docker version : 27.2.0


The documentation mentions skip, skipPush and skipTags properties
https://dmp.fabric8.io/#config-image-build
Otherwise, move the plugin to some docker build profile
